# how to test Memory isolation between kvm virtual machine in the ovirt

Tags: kvm

In the ovirt, there is more than one virtual machine on the one node, than what method we use to detect between virtual machines are isolated from each other?

Answer (score 0):

verifying isolation between virtual machines is really a tedious task. I give suggestions to start your work.
1) write inline assembly to be run from one virtual machine in order to access the files or some secrets.also try to kill process in one Vm from other VM.

2) study side channel attacks for vsphere and try to launch them in your setup

3) try to find footprints of process running in VM outside of that VM. read http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_oak12memento.pdf for some techniques